# Compute $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {1}{k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

OK..so the original problem is to compute $\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac{(k+2)}{(k+1)}$.

I have resolved the sum into its partial fractions as:

$\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac{1}{1}$ $+$
$\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac{1}{(k+1)}$

The first is non trial (which is 99) but the second is somewhat  similar to the harmonic series ($1$+$\frac{1}{2}$+$\frac {1}{3}+...$) except that it starts at $\frac {1}{2}$ instead of at $1$. What is the way forward here? I mean what is the  general n-form of the second sum? Thank you all...I appreciate it!

Comment: You can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number but I do not see anything interesting here. The sum in your first line is $$ \frac{287770507179993261645194049069528361390367}{
  2788815009188499086581352357412492142272}.$$ Are you sure the problem is not about $$
\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{99} {\frac{{k + 2}}{{k + 1}}} ?
$$

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{99}\frac{1}{(k+1)}=\sum_{k=2}^{100}\frac{1}{k}=H_{100}-1$, where $H_n$ is the harmonic number.

Comment: Thanks James...Is there another way  that may not involve the Harmonic number ?

Comment: Hi Garry ..no the problem is that of finding the  partial sum in terms of n.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Tchills If there was a simple way to represent the sum, it would also imply a simple closed formula for $H_n$. I am not aware of any simple closed formula for $H_n$.

Comment: Whe $\sum_{k=1}^{99} \frac 1{k+1} = \sum_{k=2}^{100} \frac 1k = \sum_{k=1}^{100} \frac 1k -1$.  And $\sum_{k=1}^{100} \frac 1k$ is the one hundredtrh harmonic number which can be googled and seen to be $\frac {14466636279520351160221518043104131447711}{2788815009188499086581352357412492142272}$ so your answer would be $98 +  \frac {14466636279520351160221518043104131447711}{2788815009188499086581352357412492142272}$ ... bleah....(https://www.dcode.fr/harmonic-number for example)

Comment: @Gary "Are you sure the problem is not about..."  I'm confused.  That is exactly what the op wrote.

Comment: @fleablood Note the difference between $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$.

Comment: Dope slap... yes, that makes a *lot* of sense.  And it makes for an "aha! Insight!" type question.

Answer (score 1):

In [this](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/322248.322255) article it is shown that harmonic number $H_n$ does not have a formula as rational function of $n$. However if you want an approximate answer then you can use the following approximation
$$H_n \approx \log n + \gamma$$ where $\gamma$ is called  [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) whose approximate value is $0.577$.

Comment: The non-existence of a rational function expression follows also from the asymptotics. No rational function of $n$ can grow like a logarithm.